# How to create multiple presentations from one source

Tags: organisation

I have a huge LaTeX Beamer presentation consisting of multiple parts included as single source files.

Now I'll have to create another presentation which is very similar to the first one, it will contain about 90% of the slides of the first one with some additional material, but not congruent with those whole files.

As I'll have to care and update both for a while in the future, it would be best to create both from the same source code.

How can I realize that?
Splitting out everything in single files that are included from different master documents would work, but fragment everything in too many pieces.

Maybe I could use some environment variable set in the SHELL environment/makefile and then conditionally exclude the irrelevant parts of the slides for both?

Comment: What about using `\def`s and `\ifx` inside the source? Or better using LaTeX `ifs`?

Comment: Probably you are looking for `\includeonlyframes{list,of,frames,to,process}` but `\input{file} % Comments` is also a good option IMHO. with a consistent naming method of the files and directories, is not too hard to maintain. Then, the main file become a an index where comment/uncomment lines (frames) is very easy.

Comment: Related: [Compile only outline and comments/ Synopsis view](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50105/3345) and related links. You could use the comment package as an advanced form of the `\def`s @Astrinus suggested. The method @Fran suggested should also work.

Comment: Worst case, you can make each page a macro in the source file and only expand the pages you intend to use (just don't use numbers in the macro names)

Comment: Thanks for all the good the good tips! I think I'll go the includes first and see how far it will work out without further macros...