# Generating two different pdfs out of one tex file?

Tags: pdftex, languages

Is there a way to automatically generate two different pdf files with one run of pdflatex?

I would like to produce a german and an english version of the same document. I know how to define a command acting as a switch (e.g. `\germanenglish`), which I could use like

```
\germanenglish{Deutscher Text}{english text}
```

Yet the best solution for now is defining a command in the preamble used to switch the switch. More convenient, however, would be a way of having latex produce

```
filename_de.tex
filename_en.tex
```

with one click.

Comment: Something like my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258687/generate-multiple-pdfs-for-different-document-versions-in-a-single-build ???

Comment: Of course, there are other answers as well, not only mine ... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- of course two different pdf files can be generated from a single tex file, but, as far as i've seen, not at the same time, which is what is asked here.  if "one run of pdflatex" could be considered to be what would be produced with two different arara directives specified at the top of the file, then yes, but that would actually be two separate runs of pdflatex, just done in one continuous "session".  (nit picker at work.)

Comment: Related: [Polyglot note-keeping?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49819/polyglot-note-keeping/49827#49827)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to solve the problem as follows:

```
\ProvidesPackage{altlang}[2015/09/20 Alternative Languages Package]

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{alternativelanguage}
\togglefalse{alternativelanguage}

\IfSubStr*{\jobname}{\secondlang}{%
   \toggletrue{alternativelanguage}%
}{%
   \togglefalse{alternativelanguage}%
}

\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\iftoggle{alternativelanguage}{#2}{#1}}

\newcommand{\producealternativelanguage}{%
   \iftoggle{alternativelanguage}{}{%
      \StrBefore*{\jobname}{\firstlang}[\substrbefore]
      \StrBehind*{\jobname}{\firstlang}[\substrbehind]
      \edef\myjobname{\substrbefore\secondlang\substrbehind}
      \def\space{ }
      \immediate\write18{pdflatex --jobname=\myjobname\space \jobname.tex}
   }
}

\endinput
```

Usage:

```
%% file myfile_de.tex
...
\newcommand{\firstlang}{_de}
\newcommand{\secondlang}{_en}

\usepackage{altlang}

...
\producealternativelanguage

\begin{document}
\lang{deutscher Text}{english text}
\end{document}

%% pdflatex-ing with shell-escape being enabled
%% will produce myfile_de.tex and myfile_en.tex
```